# How to force Raspi audio output to HDMI and keep it sticky?

Tags: audio, hdmi, raspberry-pi-os-bookworm

I am running an headless Raspi 3B+ (bookworm) to play audio to a C4 system. The audio is sent out through HDMI but it happens that if I switch off the C4, amplifier the raspi defaults to the analog audio jack and when I switch on the C4 again it doesn't switch back to HDMI.

I would like to keep it sticky on the HDMI output, as I am not using the jack.

This is my .asound.rc:

```
pcm.!default {
  type asym
  playback.pcm {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "output"
  }
  capture.pcm {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "input"
  }
}

pcm.output {
  type hw
  card 0
}

ctl.!default {
  type hw
  card 0
}
```

and this is /proc/asound/cards:

```
 0 [b1             ]: bcm2835_hdmi - bcm2835 HDMI 1
                      bcm2835 HDMI 1
 1 [Headphones     ]: bcm2835_headpho - bcm2835 Headphones
                      bcm2835 Headphones
/proc/asound/cards (END)
```

I have also set the HDMI on raspi.config, but it is not persistent if I switch off the C4 amplifier.